# How do I program a key for a 2005 Toyota Corolla?

Tags: toyota, key

I bought a blank replacement key for my 2005 Toyota Corolla and will have a locksmith cut it to match the existing master key.   How to I program the car to recognize the new key for starting the ignition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand this key is not programmable without the Toyota scan tools so you may have to take it to the dealer.

> TYPE 3
>
> TOYOTA 4Runner 2003 2004 2005 Avalon   2005 Camry   2004 2005 2006
>   2007 Corolla  2005 Highlander 2004 2005 Land Cruiser 2003 2004 2005 
>   Prius  2004 Sienna 2004 Solara 2004 Tacoma 2005
>
> You can not program in this key yourself. You need to take your car
>   and your key to either the dealer or to a local locksmith that has the
>   Toyota key programming software.

[SOURCE](http://www.keymam.com/news_view.asp?newsid=27)